# Abort API calls when switching between views in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My WPF app has a bar on the top with buttons which allow the users to switch between screens.

XAML:

```
// FEE SURVEY BUTTON
<Menu:Btn
    Command="{Binding FeeSurveyCommand}"
    IsChecked="{Binding NavBar.FeeSurvey}"
    Style="{StaticResource NavButton}">
</Menu:Btn>

// PRACTICE SNAPSHOT BUTTON
<Menu:Btn
    Command="{Binding PracticeSnapshotCommand}"
    IsChecked="{Binding NavBar.PracticeSnapshot}"
    Style="{StaticResource NavButton}">
</Menu:Btn>

// CONTENTS which dynamically changes when users click on the buttons
<ContentControl
    x:Name="Pages"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="25,0"
    Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private object _currentView;
public object CurrentView
{
    get { return _currentView; }
    set { _currentView = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); }
}    

public ICommand FeeSurveyCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand PracticeSnapshotCommand { get; set; }

private void FeeSurvey(object obj)
        {
            CurrentView = new FeeSurveyVM();
        }

private void PracticeSnapshot(object obj)
        {
            CurrentView = new PracticeSnapshotVM();
        }

// CONSTRUCTOR
public MainViewVM()
 {
     FeeSurveyCommand = new RelayCommand(FeeSurvey);
     PracticeSnapshotCommand = new RelayCommand(PracticeSnapshot);
 }
```

So, when the user clicks on a button, it will create an instance of a view model (example: `FeeSurveyVM` or `PracticeSnapshotVM`). Each view model is associated with a view. When the new view is rendered, there are several APIs are called. The issue I am encountering is when the user switch views, the API calls are not aborted. Let say someone switches back and forth between these views, and if there are errors in the API calls (for example, 404, 400, 500 error), a bunch of error message of the previously visited views shows up even though I have switched to another view.

In details, for example, when FeeSurvey tab is selected, FeeSurveyVM is created, and in the constructor, it calls an API to get the list of fee surveys:
FeeSurveyVM.cs

```
// Constructor
Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = new()
{
    {"startdate", "2023-01-01"},
    {"enddate", "2024-01-01"},
};

var res = await ApiCalls.AuthGetApiWithHeader<JObject>("/fee_surveys", queryParams);

// Then Do something with the data returned from API call
```

ApiCalls.cs:

```
 public static async Task<T> AuthGetApiWithHeader<T>(string endpoint, Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = null)
 {
     try
     {
         using var client = new HttpClient();

         // some logic to get the request URL

         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);

         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
             {
                 return default;
             }
             else
             {
                 // Process the successful response
                 T result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                 return result;

             }
         }
         else
         {
             HandleApiCallErrorsAsync(response);  // function to handle error
             return default;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         MessageBoxHelper.ShowCustomMessageBox("error", "ERROR", "An error occurred. Please try again.");
         return default;
     }
 }
```

Is there a way to cancel/abort these API calls when the view changes? I have been looking for a solution but no luck.

Comment: How do you make those API calls? Ideally you'd pass a cancellation token to those calls, tied to a `CancellationTokenSource` that you can cancel when you switch views.

Comment: Share the code of how you are making those API calls, so that we will be able to help further.

Comment: Without knowing any details (you didn't provide them) you have two general options. 1) The API you interact with supports cancellation to enable you to cancel longrunning operations 2) The API doesn't support cancellation so that you have to wait for completion. In this case you can decide to swallow any messages and responses and ignore the result and treat the operation as virtually cancelled. This works best when the relevant API calls are asynchronous or executed on a background thread. If you have access to the API you should implement it cancelable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Before making an `API` call, instantiate a `CancellationToken`, and then call its `Cancel method` whenever you want to cancel the operation.

```
//A Cancelation token
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var res = await ApiCalls.AuthGetApiWithHeader<JObject>("/fee_surveys", queryParams,cts.Token);
```

So change `AuthGetApiWithHeader<T>` like this:

```
AuthGetApiWithHeader<T>(string endpoint,CancellationToken  token=null, Dictionary<string,string> queryParams = null){}
```

Then in `AuthGetApiWithHeader` modify `HttpClient`:

```
 using var client = new HttpClient();

//some logic to get the request URL
var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl, token);
```

When you want to cancel `HttpClient` calls, you can use the `CancellationToken` in the **viewModel**.

```
cts.Cancel();
```